# How can I install new theme in Magneto ?

Tags: magento

I want to install new theme in magento and I have also followed step of this link (https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/magento/magento_themes.htm) but I am not abling to get theme in magento. Please suggest me how can I install theme in magento ?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [magento theme install](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10824802/magento-theme-install)

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the pre-built theme, then in magento project folder navigate to

> app/design/frontend/default

Place your theme folder here.

Now to activate your theme. Log in to your admin panel.

Navigate to

> system->configuration

Click in the design tab in the left hand side
Under the **"Pakage Name"** put you package name i.e "**default**"  in this case and under you theme In the "**Template**" put your theme name "**Your_theme_name**" i.e your theme folder name that you copied inside **default** directory.

If you are creating a new theme, just create a new folder inside **default** directory and follow the step as described above.

In this way you can install a new theme.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how theme you want to use is distributed. If it is a package, just extract it to your root folder and you should get proper folders in `skin` and `app/design` dirs and what you need to do then is to set correct package and / or theme in backend (Configuration > Web > Design). For full package theme name would probably always be `default`. Although if you are only adding new theme, you should pick its name `app/design/frontend/default/{theme_name}` and same in `skin` folder (if it includes some additional css, images and / or javascript).